# Pass array of objects to MVC Controller Action via JQuery AJAX, Action Parameter is always null

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having following controller action in ASP.NET MVC

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Save(List<Mixing> lstmixing)
    {
        int TMPMIXINGNO=0;
        foreach (Mixing mixing in lstmixing)
        {
            TMPMIXINGNO = mixing.MIXINGNO;
            Mixing obj = new Mixing();
            obj.MIXINGNO = mixing.MIXINGNO;
            obj.CARET = mixing.CARET;
            obj.PRICE = mixing.PRICE;
            obj.DATE = mixing.DATE;
            obj.DETAILS = mixing.DETAILS;
            obj.CREATE_TIMESTAMP = DateTime.Now;
            obj.LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP = DateTime.Now;
            obj.INVOICEDETAILID = mixing.INVOICEDETAILID;
            db.Mixings.Add(obj);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        var result = db.Mixings.Where(p => p.MIXINGNO == TMPMIXINGNO).ToList();
        return Json(result);

    }
```

I am planning to send array of object of type `mixing` to `List<Mixing> lstmixing` with following jquery ajax code. But `lstmixing` is always null.

```
btnAdd.click(function () {
        var DATA = [];
        var ID = $(".invoiceno").val();
        var serviceURL = '@Url.Action("Save", "Mixing")';
        $(".invoice_table tbody tr").each(function () {
            var MIXINGNO = $(".mixingno").val();
            var DATE = $(".date").val();
            var INVOICEDETAILID = $(this).find("td:first").text();
            var CARET = $(this).find("td:eq(3) input").val();
            var PRICE = $(this).find("td:eq(2)").text();
            var DETAILS = $(".details").val();

            if (CARET != "") {
                DATA.push("{'MIXINGNO':'" + MIXINGNO + "','DATE': '" + DATE + "','INVOICEDETAILID': '" + INVOICEDETAILID + "','CARET': '" + CARET + "','PRICE': '" + PRICE + "','DETAILS': '" + DETAILS + "'}");
            }


        })
        alert(DATA);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: serviceURL,
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'lstmixing': "[" + DATA + "]" }),
            traditional:true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var str = "";
                $.each(data, function () {
                    var obj = $(this)[0];
                    str += "<tr>";
                    str += "<td>" + obj.ID + "</td>";
                    str += "<td class='text-right'>" + parseFloat(obj.CARET).toFixed(2) + "</td>";
                    str += "<td class='text-right'>" + parseFloat(obj.PRICE).toFixed(2) + "</td>";
                    str += "<td><input type='text' class='form-control text-right'' /></td>";
                    str += "</tr>";
                });
                $(".invoice_table tbody").html(str);
            }

        });
    });
```

**JSON REQUEST PAYLOAD IN GOOGLE CHROME Developer Tools-Network**

```
lstmixing:"[{'MIXINGNO':'2','DATE': '20/01/2017','INVOICEDETAILID': '10','CARET': '100','PRICE': '100.00','DETAILS': 'NO'},{'MIXINGNO':'2','DATE': '20/01/2017','INVOICEDETAILID': '11','CARET': '200','PRICE': '200.00','DETAILS': 'NO'}]"
```

**Model - Mixing.cs**

```
public class Mixing
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Mixing No")]
    [Required]
    public int MIXINGNO { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DATE { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Invoice Detail ID")]
    [Required]
    public int INVOICEDETAILID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Caret")]
    [Required]
    public decimal CARET { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Price")]
    [Required]
    public decimal PRICE { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Details")]
    public string DETAILS { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime CREATE_TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
}
```

Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action parameter is `null` because you have to fix the way you are sending the data property from your ajax to this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: serviceURL,
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'lstmixing': DATA }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {...
```

And finally you have another possible problem when inserting the data in the array. I mean this line:

```
DATA.push("{'MIXINGNO':'" + MIXINGNO + "','DATE': '" + DATE + "','INVOICEDETAILID': '" + INVOICEDETAILID + "','CARET': '" + CARET + "','PRICE': '" + PRICE + "','DETAILS': '" + DETAILS + "'}");
```

You are trying to insert into the array objects like they already are objects type JSON, the way you have to do this is inserting them like javascript normal objects, like this:

```
DATA.push({
    MIXINGNO: MIXINGNO,
    DATE:  DATE,
    INVOICEDETAILID: INVOICEDETAILID,
    CARET: CARET,
    PRICE: PRICE,
    DETAILS:  DETAILS 
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Jose, your suggestion solved my problem. You were right about `push` that it should be used the way you suggested.

Comment: This does not work without changing the ajax `data` option

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 errors that result in invalid json. First to add the items to the array, use

```
DATA.push({MIXINGNO: MIXINGNO, DATE: DATE, INVOICEDETAILID: INVOICEDETAILID, CARET: CARET, PRICE: PRICE, DETAILS: DETAILS });
```

The `data` option is also incorrect (`DATA` is already an array) and it needs to be

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: serviceURL,
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'lstmixing': DATA }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
```

Note that `traditional:true,` should also be removed

Comment: `lstmixing` shows count of 2 but both its child are `null`

Comment: I have already tested it and it works. If its `null` for you then you have done something else wrong as well. Start by checking that your model has properties (with `{ get; set; }` ), not fields

Comment: I have added the model code and each field contains `{get;set;}`

Comment: I am using the same code and also I have applied your suggestion. But still `lstmixing` children are `null`

Comment: Have just spotted you other error -  it needs to be `DATA.push({ MIXINGNO: MIXINGNO, DATE': .... }); - get rid of all those quotes and `+` and generate a javascript object

Comment: Thank you @Stephen, Jose suggested the same and it did solve my problem.

Comment: The accepted answer will not work - you still need to change the ajax `data` option code

Comment: Currently its wokring with `data: JSON.stringify({ 'lstmixing': DATA  }),`

Comment: Yes (that's part of my answer) - your `data: JSON.stringify({ 'lstmixing': "[" + DATA + "]" }),` does not work :)

Comment: I have also upvoted you but I can only select one as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in the data you are sending to controller

`JSON.stringify({ 'lstmixing': "[" + DATA + "]" })`

Try with this:

`JSON.stringify(DATA)`

Comment: If i send the data the way you suggested, `lstmixing` shows length of 2 but both its child are null still.